# Finding controls inside asp:Repeater

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress, repeater

I have a repeater control populated dynamically with the following structure:

```
  <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater" OnItemDataBound="Repeater_OnItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>                
            <dx:ASPxPanel ID="ASPxPanel1" runat="server" Width="100%" >
                <dx:PanelCollection>
                    <dx:PanelContent runat="server">
                        <div class="row">            
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox1" runat="server" Width="100%"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
                            </div>                                                
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <dx:ASPxComboBox runat="server" Width="100%" ID="ComboBox"></dx:ASPxComboBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>                    
                    </dx:PanelContent>
                </dx:PanelCollection>
            </dx:ASPxPanel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>


protected void Repeater_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{        
    var combobox = e.Item.FindControl("ComboBox");        
    if (combobox != null)
        BindComboBox(ComboBox);        
}
```

Is there anyway to get the controls that make the content of the ItemTempate on the repeater's OnItemDataBound event? `FindControl()` seems to always return null

Comment: You need first find the panel and then in panel find the your combobox control

Comment: Yeah just noticed that. Thanks